# SendDirectMessageActionException when using ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElementBatch to send direct messages

Tags: apex, community, chatter-rest-api, direct-messaging

I am trying to use ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElementBatch to send **direct messages** in mass to portal users, but I am getting the following error:

`An Apex error occurred: SendDirectMessageAction.SendDirectMessageActionException: Missing required 'subjectId' parameter.`

I don't know what to put on this field as the portal user Id (recipient of the message) goes in the `ConnectApi.DirectMessageCapabilityInput.membersToAdd` attribute. When I tried putting the portal user Id here, the method sends chatter messages rather than community direct messages.

The following code (copied from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples_post_feed_element_direct_message.htm works fine and it does not ask for a subjectId. The problem shows when I add the `feedItemInput` to the `ConnectApi.BatchInput`

Has anyone successfully used the postFeedElementBatch  to post direct messages to portal users?

```java
        //This code works fine and It does NOT include subjectId
        // Define the FeedItemInput object to pass to postFeedElement
        ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();

        ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
        textSegmentInput.text = 'Hi there';

        // The MessageBodyInput object holds the text in the post
        ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
        messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();
        messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput);
        feedItemInput.body = messageBodyInput;

        // The FeedElementCapabilitiesInput object holds the capabilities of the feed item.
        // For this feed item, we define a direct message capability to hold the member(s) and the subject.        
        List<String> memberIds = new List<String>();
        memberIds.add('0057E0000095');

        ConnectApi.DirectMessageCapabilityInput dmInput = new ConnectApi.DirectMessageCapabilityInput();
        dmInput.subject = 'Saying hello';
        dmInput.membersToAdd = memberIds;

        ConnectApi.FeedElementCapabilitiesInput feedElementCapabilitiesInput = new ConnectApi.FeedElementCapabilitiesInput();
        feedElementCapabilitiesInput.directMessage = dmInput;

        feedItemInput.capabilities = feedElementCapabilitiesInput;

        // Post the feed item. 
        ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(Network.getNetworkId(), feedItemInput);
```

```java
    //This code fails with: An Apex error occurred: SendDirectMessageAction.SendDirectMessageActionException: Missing required 'subjectId' parameter.
    private static void sendBatchDirectMessages(DirectMessageDetails messageDetail) {

        List<ConnectApi.BatchInput> batchInputs = new List<ConnectApi.BatchInput>();

        for(String userId : messageDetail.userIds) {         
            batchInputs.add(createBatchInput(userId, messageDetail.subject, messageDetail.body));
        }

        List<ConnectApi.BatchResult> postFeedResult = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElementBatch(Network.getNetworkId(), batchInputs);        
    }

    private static ConnectApi.BatchInput createBatchInput(String userId, String subject, String messageBody) {

        // Define the FeedItemInput object to pass to postFeedElement
        ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();

        ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
        textSegmentInput.text = messageBody;

        // The MessageBodyInput object holds the text in the post
        ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
        messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();
        messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput);
        feedItemInput.body = messageBodyInput;
        //feedItemInput.subjectId = 'me'; //I tried with this but it does not work

        // The FeedElementCapabilitiesInput object holds the capabilities of the feed item.
        // For this feed item, we define a direct message capability to hold the member(s) and the subject.        
        List<String> memberIds = new List<String>();
        memberIds.add(userId);

        ConnectApi.DirectMessageCapabilityInput dmInput = new ConnectApi.DirectMessageCapabilityInput();
        dmInput.subject = subject;
        dmInput.membersToAdd = memberIds;

        ConnectApi.FeedElementCapabilitiesInput feedElementCapabilitiesInput = new ConnectApi.FeedElementCapabilitiesInput();
        feedElementCapabilitiesInput.directMessage = dmInput;

        feedItemInput.capabilities = feedElementCapabilitiesInput;

        return new ConnectApi.BatchInput(feedItemInput);
    }
```